# Integrating Gaussian over cube

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

Is it possible to evaluate the following integral
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \dots \int_{-1}^1 e^{- (\mathbf x- \mathbf y)^T A (\mathbf x-\mathbf y)} dx_1 \dots dx_n
$$
where $\mathbf x, \mathbf y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $A$ is positive definite matrix.

I have no idea how to do it for general matrix $A$. Is it even possible to write down the answer with nice formula?

Comment: Your matrix is not symmetric, right?

Comment: It is symmetric. Even if it would not be symmetric then the answer would not depend on its anti-symmetric part.

Comment: evaluate in what sense? you can't even express $\int_{-1}^1 e^{-x^2}$ as rational number...

Comment: @user251257 Well you can write it in terms of error function which is well studied function and many of its properties are known.

Comment: I'm struggling with this also, but it seems hard to do without information on $A$. I'd like to be able to do some change of variables so that it reduces to product of error functions, but I can't tell how to calculate the limits of integration for general $A$. Possible that one could get an estimate if $A$ satisfies something like pairwise incoherence.